# Some questions on creating app bundle of python/wxpython source code

Tags: python, macos, wxpython, pyinstaller

I created an simple 'Hello World'-like app based on wxpython, the source code is copied on the official website of wxpython

about at the bottom in "Putting it all together" in  http://wiki.wxpython.org/Optimizing%20for%20Mac%20OS%20X
I am very sorry because when I paste the code to this page I found it cannot display correctly.

With this source code, I successfully compiled .py to an app bundle with pyInstaller(with --windowed) and py2app. Then I edit my code, change a menu option into Chinese

```
item = FileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, text = "&Open")

item = FileMenu.Append(wx.ID_ANY, text = "&打开")
```

Then I tried to compiled the source code into app bundle by py2app and pyInstaller, I found the app bundle they created didn`t work, it crashed just after my opening, and the error log from the OS console was 
[image]

but when I open the .app directory and run the UNIX executable file I found it works, and the Chinese words display without any error...

I just confirmed that i did add `# -*- coding: UTF-8 -*-` before the start of the source code

Ok....that was the problem....can anybody help me to solve this....appreciated!!!!!